# finding points that reside on a line between 2 points, in accurate segments, python

Tags: python, line, points

I have 2 points, (x0,y0) (x1,y1) which form a line L. I found the slope M.
Now I want to find 3 points between these 2 points that reside on L, that is between them in an accurate distance, meaning same distance between all points.
If I measure the distance with the "-" char, it can be something like:
p1---p2---p3---p4---p5 where p1 and p5 are my starting points.

First I thought about finding the slope by doing something like this:

```
def findSlope(p1, p2):
if (p1[0] - p2[0] != 0):
    return (p1[1] - p2[1])/p1[0] - p2[0]
else:
    return 0
```

This is pretty easy, but getting the actual points is not coming easy to me.
I thought about doing something like this:

```
def findThreePoints(p1,p2):

    slope = findSlope(p1,p2)
    c = p1[1] - slope*p1[0]
    x1 = (p1[0] + p2[0])/4
    x2 = (p1[0] + p2[0])/2
    x3 = (3*(p1[0] + p2[0]))/4
    y1 = slope*x1 + c
    y2 = slope*x2 + c
    y3 = slope*x3 + c
```

While this approach works, it is not very nice coding style/efficiency, since if I want the function to give more than 3 points, I will need it to be much longer.

Is there any built in way to do this with Numpy, or just a more efficient approach to the matter, that does not make my code look like it was written for only a certain purpose?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As simple as it gets:

```
import numpy as np

#create the points 
number_of_points=3
xs=np.linspace(x0,x1,number_of_points+2)
ys=np.linspace(y0,y1,number_of_points+2)

#print them
for i in range(len(xs)):
    print (xs[i],ys[i])
```

And it also works for horizontal or vertical lines

Comment: Perfect, EXACTLY the type of solution I was looking for. THANKS!!

Answer (score 1):

If equation of a line is

```
y = m*x + q
```

why not use a FOR loop?
Something like:

```
import numpy
#define n in the code or by input
n = 100
#define the x and y arrays with numpy.array
x = numpy.zeros(n)
y = numpy.zeros(n)    

#define the start, stop values in your code or by input
start = 1
stop = 10

#define the step, depending by n
step = (stop - start)/n #if you want n points

i = 0
for a in numpy.arange (start, stop, step):
 x[i] = a 
 y[i] = m*a + q
 i = i + 1 #there are better ways to do this
```

Of course this does not work for vertical lines, but there is no problem in finding points for these lines (x is constant)

Comment: Thank you, this answer tought me about the thinking process, but the accepted answer is actually the magic I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a **general** `numpy` **one liner** following the same interface as the [`line_nd`](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api/skimage.draw.html#skimage.draw.line_nd) method from `skimage`, but that works for **any n dimensional points**, not only for 2D:

```
import numpy as np

line_nd_np = lambda start, stop, num_points: tuple([np.linspace(start[i], stop[i], num=num_points) for i in range(len(start))])

line_nd_np(start=(0,0,0), stop=(1,1,1), num_points=3)
```

So, following the same interface as `line_nd`, `line_nd_np` returns a tuple with numpy arrays of each coordinate one by one (e.g. (xs, ys, zs,...)).

```
(array([0. , 0.5, 1. ]), array([0. , 0.5, 1. ]), array([0. , 0.5, 1. ]))
```

If one wants **only an array with points on the line** between start and end, the one liner can become:

```
import numpy as np

line_points = lambda start, stop, num_points=100: np.vstack([np.linspace(start[i], stop[i], num=num_points) for i in range(len(start))]).T 

line_points(start=(0,0,0), end=(1,1,1), num_points=3)
```

Then, one can get:

```
array([[0. , 0. , 0. ],
       [0.5, 0.5, 0.5],
       [1. , 1. , 1. ]])
```